# Is there any way to Install from grub command line?

Tags: grub2, system-installation

I have a USB stick that has the Ubuntu 21.04 install image on it.  I know for 100% certain that it works because I JUST installed Ubuntu on an old laptop,  with the exact same stick.  Now I am trying on a REALLY old laptop. Toshiba satellite that is at least 15 years old.  I have a old version of Ubuntu on it already,  but I want to wipe it and start over.

But the laptop simply will not boot of the thumb drive.  I have it set to use USB as the first bootable drive,  but it is not working.

I CAN get to a grub command line.  So I am wondering,  is there any way I can start the install process from the grub command line,  or start an update from 18.10 with the USB stick mounted?

Comment: By any chance did you made that USB with Rufus?

Comment: Old laptop was probably BIOS/MBR? And newer system UEFI/gpt? ChanganAuto's question is because Rufus normally makes USB flash drive as either BIOS or UEFI, but not both. Many other tools create installer that boots in either mode, but then you have to choose from UEFI boot menu UEFI:xxxx or xxxx (which is BIOS/CSM/Legacy boot) when booting flash drive. Once installed then system must be set to boot in that mode. If UEFI hardware better to install in UEFI boot mode on gpt partitioned drive.